# Convert numeric entities into readable format

Tags: java, database, string, unicode, utf

I have the following string stored in the database which is in [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) format.

```
&#1603;&#1606;&#1578; &#1602;&#1583; &#1583;&#1582;&#1604;&#1578; &#1576;&#1575;&#1604;&#1601;&#1593;&#1604; &#1601;&#1610; &#1605;&#1603;&#1575;&#1606; &#1570;&#1582;&#1585; &#1605;&#1606;
```

Now, I want to convert that string into a readable format. In Java, how can I do that?

Comment: That's not a Unicode format, it's XML/HTML character references. Having this in your database where you expected literal characters is a big data quality smell. You can read them by unescaping them as outlined by Andrzej, but in the long run you need to fix whatever put this data in in the first place. HTML character references in your submitted form data are often a sign that you have not served your form page as UTF-8.

Comment: I want that string in that language only, e.g. if the string was in urdu then it should display urdu only not unicode characters.

Comment: ? Urdu is Unicode characters. `&#`...`;` is a HTML character reference escape. It is not itself anything to do with Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are HTML entities, you need some sort of library method that will resolve them into the characters that they represent.

Apache Commons has `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml` for example, and I'm sure there are plenty of others.

If you really want to roll something yourself, for this particular case you could tokenise the numbers between `&#` and `;`, parse them as a hex int, and call `Character.toChars` to convert them to Java characters.  It'll take more work and contain more bugs than using a library, though, and I'm sure there's edge cases in the spec which I'm glossing over.

Either should give the result

> ᘃᘆᕸ ᘂᖃ ᖃᖂᘄᕸ ᕶᕵᘄᘁᖓᘄ ᘁᘐ ᘅᘃᕵᘆ ᕰᖂᖅ ᘅᘆ

(By the way, I think you should be more specific about what you mean by 'readable format'.  I can *read* that string right now - it's a sequence of entity references.  You're a developer, be precise!)

Comment: Readable means if the string is in French or Urdu then it should display that thing only not unicodes of that.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani I think you've misunderstood Andrzej, he's actually solved your problem. You need to call the unescapeHtml function for each character while building the page. Then it will automatically use the correct character set.

Comment: @Bhavik - but the string **isn't** in French or Urdu, it's in US-ASCII and it's a string of HTML entity references. :)  You want to *resolve* these references, to transform the string into a difference on based on a set of rules.  Which is valid, sure, but it's much clearer to refer to it as "resolve the entity refs" rather than "make readable".  Anyway, this is all a bit offtopic - to solve your problem you need to call an appropriate method to unescape the string.

Comment: (Oh, and [apparently](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1400.pdf) these characters are Canadian Aboriginal syllabics.  Who knew?)

Comment: (Ah, they're decimal character references not hex, so in the Arabic block rather than Canadian. The string decodes to `كنت قد دخلت بالفعل في مكان آخر من`.)

Comment: I want the same output as above. from the string &#1578; &#1602;. How can I do that ?